# web application, make user_id from database public in url

Tags: url, web-applications

I just want to know if it is good practice or not to add user_id from db to the url of user_profile in a web application for example like `www.example.com/john-smith-4233`. The url would actually consist of first_name last_name and user_id from db. I would like to know whether it would be a good or a bad practice. The "john-smith-4233" part would then be a unique username, and everyone could find a person according to url when typing for instance something like this "example john smith" into google. Is there a better way to do something like this? I was also considering a way to add a number after username, only when a user with this first_name and last_name exists ... but for that I would have to always query the DB, so I am looking for the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about the same problem recently. I don't think there is an "established best practice." The problem I see with your solution is that most of the time "firstname-lastname" is probably unique and you are attaching a messy number onto it for no reason. One thing you might try would be to add a database field called "canonical_name" and each time you create an account, you check whether "firstname-lastname" is already used. If it is not, then "firstname-lastname" becomes the canonical name for the new user. If it is used, then you affix a number (perhaps a low number 1,2,3 etc) and the canonical name becomes "firstname_lastname_1".

I think this is something like what Facebook does.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same, but I have also considered that I have to always check the database, when new user signs in. Maybe I am overreacting and want to have everything just perfect. I might as well go for this option. The database is meant for such things, isn't it?

Comment: A new user signup is a relatively rare operation (compared to something like a page-view). Doing 1 extra query per user-signup shouldn't impact your performance noticeably.